# search a file for #define directives and then store them in variables using bash

Tags: bash

I have a file which has

```
#define x 1
#define y 2
```

I have to read the contents of this file and then store them in variables like $x = 1 and $y = 2 using bash

Comment: I am new to bash so I really dont know how to proceed

Comment: Sure, but you could at least try Googling for some ideas first...

Comment: I tried to search for pattern using sed command sed 's/#define x/' file_name

Answer (score 1):

This should work in most cases:

```
eval $(sed -e "s/#define \([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)  *\(.*\)/\1='\2'/g" inputfile)
```

It fails for macros expanding to tokens containing single quotes. It also doesn't deal with tabs in places where whitespace can occur.

And beware of the gory details of the C language, which most, if not all the answers neglect:

- There can be whitespace (spaces and tabs) and comments before the `#`
- There can be whitespace and comments between `#` and `define`
- There can be a comment between `define` and the macro identifier
- There are function-like macros looking different, i.e. `#define square(x) ((x) * (x))`

This should give you an idea why it is almost always a bad idea to parse a complex language with anything other than, well, a parser for that language. If you have gcc, you can make it deal with the first three bullets above. The idea is to make gcc's preprocessor dump the macros in a canonical format without comments and tabs and then process that:

```
eval $(gcc -E -dM -x c -std=c89 inputfile |
       grep -v '^#define _'|
       sed -e "s/#define \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\1='\2'/g")
```

The grep filters out all the gcc internal predefined macros like `_LP64`. If you run this on

```
/**/    #       /**/    define/**/      x       /**/1
```

(where each whitespace is a tab) it will result in

```
eval x=1
```

For quick and dirty hacks you might get away with using the shell, though. :-)

Comment: It might be safer to use `declare` instead of `eval`, since you don't  need to execute any code, just define variables. However, then the quotes you insert also become part of the variable value; it might be difficult to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

***Something*** to get you started:

```
while read check varname value; do # Read the 3 values from each line
    if [[ $check == \#define ]]; then # Check if 1st value is #define
        export $varname=$value # If it is assign variables.
    fi
done < myfile
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat myfile
#define x 1
#define y 2
$ while read check varname value; do
> if [[ $check == \#define ]]; then
> export $varname=$value
> fi
> done < myfile 
$ echo $x
1
$ echo $y
2
```

#### Test #2

```
$ cat myfile2 
#define x happy
#define y nappy
$ while read check varname value; do
> if [[ $check == \#define ]]; then
> export $varname=$value
> fi
> done < myfile2 
$ echo $x
happy
$ echo $y
nappy
```

Comment: The shell is not perl :-) You've got a bunch of extra semicolons you might want to clean up.

Comment: @Jens SIR YES SIR! :) Actually wrote it as a one-liner and then formatted it for OP so forgot to remove `;`

Comment: it gives me an error syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: @user1483794 I added a test execution.